# TypeErrror: data.forEach when rendering date from API-call

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, foreach

I'm getting an error:

> **TypeError: data.forEach is not a function**

I've tried with `data = JSON.parse(data)` but then I get another error:

> **SyntaxError: "[object Object]" is not valid JSON**

I suppose it is because the datarecords are contained in an array with key `content` as you can see below. Is there an easy way to get to the datarecords that are in the array `content`?

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', initClubApi);

function initClubApi(){
    renderFromApi("games/team/2").then(function(data){               
        renderTeams(data);
    });
}

function renderFromApi(url){
    return fetch(`https://www.xyz.be/api/clubapi/${url}`).then(function(response){        
        return response.json();
    });
}

function renderTeams(data){
    const target = document.querySelector("#teams-schedule");
    target.innerHTML = "";
    console.log(data);
    data.forEach(function(row){
        
        const teamData = `
            <div class="date">${row.id}</div>
            <div class="wrapper">
                <div class="team-name">${row.homeTeamId}</div>
                <div class="versus">VS</div>
                <div class="team-name">${row.awayTeamId}</div>
            </div>
        `;
        target.innerHTML += teamData;
    });
}
```

An example of the data below (just one row)

```json
{
    "content":[
        {
            "viewGameReport":false,
            "id":1632,
            "date":"2023-08-17 19:30",
            "time":"1970-01-01 01:00",
            "cancelled":false,
            "status":0,
            "goalsHomeTeam":2,
            "goalsAwayTeam":2,
            "homeClub":{
                "id":1690,
                "name":"Sporting Keiem",
                "abbreviation":"Sporting Keiem",
                "logo":"https://dfaozfi7c7f3s.cloudfront.net/logos/extra_groot/1690.png?v=1",
                "logoSmall":"https://dfaozfi7c7f3s.cloudfront.net/logos/klein/1690.png?v=1",
                "version":1
            },
            "awayClub":{
                "id":159,
                "name":"K s v Veurne",
                "abbreviation":"K s v Veurne",
                "logo":"https://dfaozfi7c7f3s.cloudfront.net/logos/extra_groot/159.png?v=1",
                "logoSmall":"https://dfaozfi7c7f3s.cloudfront.net/logos/klein/159.png?v=1",
                "version":1
            },
            "competitionType":"Vriendschappelijk",
            "homeTeamId":null,
            "awayTeamId":2
        }
    ]
}
```

And the full JSON-result:

```json
{
    "content":[],
    "pageable":{},
    "last":true,
    "totalElements":40,
    "totalPages":1,
    "first":true,
    "numberOfElements":40,
    "number":0,
    "size":2000,
    "sort":{},
    "empty":false
}
```

Comment: `data.content.forEach` ?

Comment: @Kosh this gives me also the SyntaxError: SyntaxError: "[object Object]" is not valid JSON

Comment: `this gives me also the SyntaxError` ...which you won't show?

Comment: Sorry, I wanted to refer as the same SyntaxError in my original post SyntaxError: "[object Object]" is not valid JSON

Comment: that would mean that `data.content` is an instance of Object too which contradicts to your data example provided.

Comment: @Kosh I added the result of my API-call. I just need the data in *content*

Comment: If you still have `data = JSON.parse(data)` in your code, remove it. Just use `data.content.forEach`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I access and process nested objects, arrays, or JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/how-can-i-access-and-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Answer (score 0):

> SyntaxError: "[object Object]" is not valid JSON

You are getting this error as you are trying to parse the JSON object. `JSON.parse()` is useful only to parse the JSON string into JSON object.

> TypeError: data.forEach is not a function

You are getting above error as you are trying to iterate an object (as per the log output you mentioned), [`Array.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) is used to iterate an array not an object.

Try this **:**

```
data.content.forEach(row => {
  ...
})
```